# Getting async/await to work with superagent

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await, superagent

I'm missing something in my syntax here but not sure what:

I'm trying to nock this.  But I get `expected undefined to equal 'pXVCJ9.eyJpYXQ'`

**Test.js**

```
describe('User API', () => {
    let email, password, requestBody

    beforeEach(() => {
      email = 'someperson@gmail.com'
      password = 'password'
      requestBody = {
        session: '05833a20-4035',
        token: 'pXVCJ9.eyJpYXQ' }

      nock('https://someurl/')
        .get('users/sessions')
        .reply(200, requestBody)
    })

    it('returns user session for login', async () => {
        const data = await UserApi.login(email, password)

        expect(data.token).to.equal(requestBody.token)
        expect(data.session).to.equal(requestBody.session)
    })
})
```

**UserApi.js**

```
import request from 'superagent'

export const endpoint = 'https://someurl/'

const login = (email, password) => async () => {
  try {
    return await request
      .get(`${endpoint}/users/sessions`)
      .send({ email: email, password: password })
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  } catch (err) {
      //todo: implement this
  }
}

export default { login }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few issues:

```
const login = (email, password) => async () => { ... }
```

This makes `login` a function that returns an async function. It should be an async function itself, so this:

```
const login = async (email, password) => { ... }
```

Next, in your `nock` setup, you're not prefixing the path with a `/`, so `nock` won't be able to match the request. Easy fix:

```
  nock('https://someurl')
    .get('/users/sessions')
    .reply(...);
```

Lastly, `superagent` will return the response data as `response.body` or, in your case, `data.body`. So the assertions should look like this:

```
expect(data.body.token).to.equal(requestBody.token)
expect(data.body.session).to.equal(requestBody.session)
```

Comment: Thank Robert I didn't realize the first issue especially